# Align different time series

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to "capture" some points within a bar.
The points represent 36 values on a monthly basis for 3 years.
The bars represent 3 values on a yearly basis for the same 3 years.

If you run the code you can see that some point of the first year are maybe captured by the bar of the second year and that the points of the 3rd year are "running out" of the last bar.

How can I align the bars and the points?

```
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(1)
df.year <- data.frame(yeardate = seq(as.Date("2010-01-01"), by = "year", length.out = 3), datevalue = abs(rnorm(3)))
df.month <- data.frame(monthdate = seq(as.Date("2010-01-01"), by = "month", length.out = 36), datevalue = abs(rnorm(36)))
df.month$inyear <- format(df.month$monthdate, "%Y") 

df.month
p <- ggplot()
p <- p +    geom_point(
            data = df.month
            ,aes(x = monthdate, y = datevalue, color=inyear)
        )
p <- p +    geom_bar(
            data = df.year
            ,aes(x = yeardate, y = datevalue)
            ,alpha=0.7 
            ,stat = "identity"
        )           
p + scale_x_date(labels = date_format("%Y"), breaks = date_breaks("years"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`geom_bar` is centering the bars on the dates given. Since the given dates are the first of the year, it is centered around the first of the year, and so much of 2012 lies outside the bar centered on 2012-01-01 (and much of that bar lies in 2011). So either center the bars in the middle of the year:

```
df.year <- data.frame(yeardate = seq(as.Date("2010-07-01"), 
                                     by = "year", 
                                     length.out = 3), 
                      datevalue = abs(rnorm(3)))
```

which gives
[image]

or draw rectangles with the exact extent that you want them to be

```
df.year <- data.frame(yearstart = seq(as.Date("2010-01-01"), 
                                      by = "year", length.out = 3),
                      yearend = seq(as.Date("2010-12-31"), 
                                    by = "year", length.out = 3),
                      datevalue = abs(rnorm(3)))
```

and replace the `geom_bar` call with

```
p <- p +    geom_rect(
            data = df.year
            ,aes(xmin = yearstart, xmax = yearend,
                 ymin = 0, ymax = datevalue)
            ,alpha=0.7
        )
```

giving

[image]